# What do you call a person with a master's degree?

Tags: translation

I'm from Sri Lanka. and I'm trying to translate a Leaving Certificate. The Principal of this specific school has a master's degree, and in Sri Lanka we give the degree holder the honor of addressing them using the title of their degree.

Answer (score 2):

You could call someone "Master," as my friends jokingly do, but no one uses that title, since it's often considered secondary to a doctorate. It's usually Mr. or Mrs./Ms., but usually the name is followed by MS (for masters of science) or the equivalent, depending on the exact degree. https://classroom.synonym.com/how-to-address-someone-with-a-masters-degree-12082474.html

Comment: Using the "Master" title would also be a very touchy subject in US-based setting.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with DWKraus that the best way to do this is by referring to their name, followed by M.S. or the equivalent of their degree:

> Elizabeth Johnson, M.S.

I've seen a similar style used when referring to someone with a bachelor's degree of science or arts, where the name is written followed by a B.S. or B.A:

> Matthias Smith, B.S.